# Inline expansion of arrays in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, expansion

I'm trying to expand an array in bash:

```
FILES=(2009q{1..4})
echo ${FILES[@]}
echo ${FILES[@]}.zip
```

Output is:

```
2009q1 2009q2 2009q3 2009q4
2009q1 2009q2 2009q3 2009q4.zip
```

But how can I expand the last line as in `echo 2009q{1..4}.zip` expansion, so that the last line looked like:

```
2009q1.zip 2009q2.zip 2009q3.zip 2009q4.zip
```

... but using array `FILES`?

Comment: `FILES=(2009q{1..4}.zip)` won't do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
FILES=(2009q{1..4})
echo ${FILES[@]/%/.zip}
```

Output:

```
2009q1.zip 2009q2.zip 2009q3.zip 2009q4.zip
```

---

From Bash's [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`: The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string. If pattern begins with '/', all matches of pattern are replaced with string. Normally only the first match is replaced. If pattern begins with '#', it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of parameter. **If pattern begins with '%', it must match at the end of the expanded value of parameter.** If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the / following pattern may be omitted. If parameter is '@' or '*', the substitution operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with '@' or '*', the substitution operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: didn't think of this, smart.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `printf`:

```
printf "%s.zip " "${FILES[@]}"

2009q1.zip 2009q2.zip 2009q3.zip 2009q4.zip
```